# setting precedence for the expression string

Tags: java, string

I have the below expression, I want to set the parenthesis "()" for each conditions in Java. I want to convert the below expression

```
String expression = "((firstname = john AND Lastname = Eleven) OR (salary = 15000 AND location = Mexico OR (firstname = mathew AND lastname = Thirteen)))";
```

as

```
String expression = "(((firstname = john) AND (Lastname = Eleven)) OR ((salary = 15000) AND (location = Mexico) OR ((firstname = mathew) AND (lastname = Thirteen))))";
```

Is there a best way to implement that?

Comment: I would suggest that you write some code.

Comment: This isn't very clear (to me). You have a string with an expression in an unknown language and you're asking us how to "implement" it.

Comment: Yes there is. I would suggest you look up the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm or 'recursive descent expression parsing'.

Comment: You'll also need a lexical analyzer as a front-end for whatever parser you end up with...

Comment: NB The redundant parentheses serve no useful purpose. What you really need here is to observe the correct operator precedence. There is a widespread but fallacious myth that expression parsers 'insert the missing parentheses'. They don't do anything of the sort.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to implement something from the ground up, you could use a simple parser/generator like [javacc](https://javacc.org/).

Comment: @EJP, that idea seems good. I am trying the way your said.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is adding the parenthesis, you can create a regular expression to match the `text[space]=[space]text` and then wrap it in parentheses using the `String#replaceAll()` method. The match can be achieved with this regex: `(\w+ = \w+)`

```
String expression = "((firstname = john AND Lastname = Eleven) OR (salary = 15000 AND location = Mexico OR (firstname = mathew AND lastname = Thirteen)))";
String replaceAll = expression.replaceAll("(\\w+ = \\w+)", "($1)");
System.out.println(replaceAll);
//(((firstname = john) AND (Lastname = Eleven)) OR ((salary = 15000) AND (location = Mexico) OR ((firstname = mathew) AND (lastname = Thirteen))))
```

If instead of matching he `=` sign you need to match other operators, the regex can be enhanced to include `>`, `<`, `>=`, `<=`, `!=`. `(\w+ (=|>|<|>=|<=|!=) \w+)` or any other you wish.

Comment: The question is about operator precedence, and this doesn't address it in any way.

Comment: Usually when an answer says "try this", it means that it hasn't been tested. Perhaps more confidence in your answer would be beneficial.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot handle operator precedence. This was proven in 1956.

Comment: Re your edit, it was  proven in 1956 that regular expressions cannot handle operator precedence. You are suggesting entirely the wrong technology. Cleary you have never either tried nor even studied this.